# Material Tailwind - How do I put a select menu inside of the dialog without it being cut off? (React)

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, headless-ui

I have a HeadlessUI dialog, and a Material Tailwind select menu within it. The problem is, when I open the menu it gets cut off at the end of the dialog. I tried even tried changing the height of the dialog its self. Nothing I did is working which is why I'm coming here.

My Code:

Select.jsx:

```
import { Option, Select } from '@material-tailwind/react'
import React from 'react'

export function CustomSelect() {
  return (
    <Select
        label="Select Version"
        animate={{
          mount: { y: 0 },
          unmount: { y: 25 },
        }}
      >
        <Option>Material Tailwind HTML</Option>
        <Option>Material Tailwind React</Option>
        <Option>Material Tailwind Vue</Option>
        <Option>Material Tailwind Angular</Option>
        <Option>Material Tailwind Svelte</Option>
      </Select>
  )
}

export default CustomSelect
```

home.jsx:

```
import { CustomSelect } from '@/widgets/generate'
import { Dialog, Transition } from '@headlessui/react'
import { Button } from '@material-tailwind/react'
import React, { Fragment, useState } from 'react'

export function Home() {
  let [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false)

  return (
    <header className="relative">
      <div className="px-4 sm:px-6 md:px-8">

        <div className="relative max-w-5xl mx-auto pt-20 sm:pt-24 lg:pt-32">
          <h1 className="text-white font-extrabold text-4xl sm:text-5xl lg:text-6xl tracking-tight text-center dark:text-white">
            Test!
          </h1>
          <p className="mt-6 text-lg text-gray-600 text-center max-w-3xl mx-auto dark:text-slate-400">
            Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat impedit eius a odio placeat molestiae perspiciatis ab modi, officia commodi? Magnam animi numquam, ipsam doloribus unde ad? Dolorem, expedita nihil.
          </p>
          <div className="mt-6 sm:mt-10 flex justify-center space-x-6 text-sm">
            <a
            >
              <Button onClick={() => setIsOpen(true)} variant="gradient" size="lg" color='deep-purple' fullWidth>
                Generate
              </Button>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <Transition appear show={isOpen} as={Fragment}>
        <Dialog as="div" className="relative z-10" onClose={setIsOpen}>
          <Transition.Child
            as={Fragment}
            enter="ease-out duration-300"
            enterFrom="opacity-0"
            enterTo="opacity-100"
            leave="ease-in duration-200"
            leaveFrom="opacity-100"
            leaveTo="opacity-0"
          >
            <div className="fixed inset-0 bg-black bg-opacity-25" />
          </Transition.Child>

          <div className="fixed inset-0 overflow-y-auto">
            <div className="flex min-h-full items-center justify-center p-4 text-center">
              <Transition.Child
                as={Fragment}
                enter="ease-out duration-300"
                enterFrom="opacity-0 scale-95"
                enterTo="opacity-100 scale-100"
                leave="ease-in duration-200"
                leaveFrom="opacity-100 scale-100"
                leaveTo="opacity-0 scale-95"
              >
                <Dialog.Panel className="w-full max-w-md transform overflow-hidden rounded-2xl bg-white p-6 text-left align-middle shadow-xl transition-all">
                  <Dialog.Title
                    as="h3"
                    className="text-lg font-medium leading-6 text-gray-900 text-center"
                  >
                    Test
                  </Dialog.Title>
                  <div className="mt-2">
                    <p className="text-sm text-gray-500 text-center">
                       Test
                    </p>
                  </div>

                  <div className='mt-2'>
                    <CustomSelect></CustomSelect>
                  </div>

                  <div className="mt-4 flex justify-center">
                    <Button onClick={() => setIsOpen(false)} variant="gradient" size="lg" color='deep-purple' fullWidth>
                      Generate
                    </Button>
                  </div>
                </Dialog.Panel>
              </Transition.Child>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Dialog>
      </Transition>
    </header>
  )
}

export default Home
```

I tried to change the size of the dialog but that didn't work, still gets cut off when the dialog ends.